# Token-2022 coin in Coinbase wallet? Please help a noob!

Tags: wallet

I swapped for a token-2022 coin on jup.ag using sol from a coinbase wallet.  Now jup is showing the transaction and the amount, but the wallet doesn't.  Not seeing it in the wallet. Does Coinbase wallet supports ??? Now, I have the Fluxb and I can't see it in the wallet, but I am afraid to disconnect the wallet from jup.ag for fear it is lost. I do have a solflare wallet (now), but not sure what to do.

Any help? Please and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure whether Coinbase wallet supports these tokens yet. But the best thing to do is to go on a Solana explorer and search your address. That’ll show your tokens, including token-2022 ones.

Disconnecting from Jupiter won’t affect your holdings either way, so don’t worry about that.

This is probably just an issue where - as you said - Coinbase wallet doesn’t display the token. But check an Explorer to know for sure :)

Comment: Thank you!  This helps!